# Show variant title if the variant quantity is less than two in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Hi I am working on a Shopify website. what I am trying to achieve is to hide the variant titles of the out of stock products from my collection page.**"Which i have completed"** So now what I am trying is to. Show the variant titles of the product which have quantity more than 2. "**This is the part where is am stuck**" Here is my code

```js
        {%- assign empty_list = true -%}
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}
  {%- comment -%}Skip the variant if it's not available{%- endcomment -%}
  {%- unless variant.available -%}
    {%- continue -%}
  {%- endunless -%}

  {%- comment -%}Print a comma unless our list is empty{%- endcomment -%}
  {%- unless empty_list -%},{%- endunless -%}
  {%- assign empty_list = false -%}

  {%- comment -%}Now print our new entry{%- endcomment -%}
    
  <span class="variant-name"> {{ variant.title }}</span>
   
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using the below code you can get the product title that has a quantity of more than 2.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}

    {% if variant.inventory_quantity > 2 %}
        {{- variant.title -}} <br>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```